# $f_k\to 0$, a.e. $\varlimsup_k t_k>0$ $\sum_k t_kf_k(x)$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_k\to 0$, a.e. $x\in E=(0,1)$. Find $t_k$ such that $\varlimsup_k t_k>0$ such that  $\sum_k t_kf_k(x)$ converges a.e.

My attempt. for any $\delta>0$, we can find $E_\delta\subset E$, such that $m(E_\delta)<\delta$, $f_k\rightrightarrows f$ for $x\in E-E_\delta$. Then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Egorov's theorem, there are sets $\{E_k\}_{k \ge 1}$ with $m(E_k)<1/k^2$ and a strictly  increasing sequence of positive integers $\{n_k\}_{k \ge 1}$, such that $f_{n_k}(x) \le 4^{-k}$ for all $x \in (0,1)\setminus E_k$ and all $k$.

The Borel Cantelli Lemma, or a  union bound, imply that $$E_* :=\cap_{m \ge 1}  \cup_{k \ge m} E_k $$
has $m(E_*)=0$.

Define $t_n=2^k$ for $n=n_k$ and $t_n=0$ for all $n \notin\{n_k\}_{k \ge 1}$.

For all $x \in (0,1)\setminus E_*$,  the series
$$\sum_n t_n f_n(x) = \sum_k 2^k f_{n_k}(x)$$
converges, since only  finitely many summands on the RHS exceed $2^{-k}$.